# Which mysql edition should I install for my CentOS server?

Tags: mysql, linux, yum

There are different mysql install packages for differential platforms.
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads

I'm using CentOS, which install package should I download?

The Generic Linux or Rethat/Oracle Enterprise Linux?

PS: I cannot install it with yum because of some irregular Transation error.

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider trying to fix yum, which will allow you to get mysql updates for security fixes etc as part of your normal updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely use the Red Hat & Oracle Enterprise Linux version on CentOS. I've always used those Rpm without any problems. CentOS aims to be 100% binary compatible with RedHat.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the Redhat version. CentOS uses RedHat source code.